# Permissions on SSH causing problems

Tags: ssh, permissions

I am trying to SSH from my local machine to my server. In the past I haven’t had to enter a password because my public key was on the server in `authorized_keys`. However, today I think some permissions have been changed on some files and it’s asking for a password every time I try to SSH.

What are the correct/default permissions for the .ssh folder and its contents on my local machine/server?

Here are my current permissions

My server

```
[root@server9987 .ssh]# ls -la
total 24
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 03:29 .
drwxr-x--- 7 root root 4096 Oct 17 03:29 ..
-rw------- 1 root root  397 Oct 16 19:11 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 root root 1675 Oct 12 02:10 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 root root  398 Oct 12 02:10 id_rsa.pub
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  830 Oct 17 03:29 known_hosts
```

My local machine

```
➜  .ssh  l
total 32
drwx------  6 Oliver  staff   204 17 Oct 00:28 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 Oliver  staff   238 16 Oct 17:28 ..
-rw-------  1 Oliver  staff   332 16 Oct 17:28 config
-rw-------  1 Oliver  staff  1766 13 Jul 11:13 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 Oliver  staff   398 13 Jul 11:13 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 Oliver  staff  3312 17 Oct 00:28 known_hosts
```

Comment: `known_hosts` should not be group writable or world writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [over in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/90465). It wasn’t the permissions on the SSH files/folders, rather it was the permission of the user directory.

Comment: That is also a requirement, yes.  When you have an issue like you have, check the log file for `sshd`.  Usually this is kept in `/var/log/secure`.  More infrequently, `/var/log/auth.log`.  Rarely in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`.  They usually tell you right off the bat what the problem is with you logging in.

Comment: Gotta admit I never had the issue where my home folder was writable by others, so I wasn't even considering that. You live, you learn :D

Answer (score 6):

You want the private key to be readable by the owner alone. It's generally a good idea to make everything in that folder readable and writable only by the owner. However, the file which allows others to login via a key must be readable by the user who is running the ssh daemon.

generally:

```
find ~/.ssh -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
chmod 755 ~/.ssh
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

***Update***
Default permissions for the ~/.ssh folder are 700 (openssh 5.9, gentoo) and some files:

```
$ ll .ssh; ll -d .ssh
-rw-r--r-- 1 jaroslav jaroslav 406 Oct 17 04:32 known_hosts
drwx------ 2 jaroslav jaroslav 4096 Oct 17 04:32 .ssh
-rw------- 1 jaroslav jaroslav 1766 Oct 17 04:37 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 jaroslav jaroslav  395 Oct 17 04:37 id_rsa.pub
```

This is after moving my original .ssh away and running **ssh hostname.org**; **ssh-keygen**. The files created by the openssh commands seem to be unaffected by **umask**

So I'm still right, and the comments/down-votes have nothing on my answer :'(.

The reason why .ssh can be 700 is because sshd is mostly run by root who can read whatever she wants no matter what. The reason sshd is mostly run by root is because the daemon needs to listen on a privileged port (<1024).

Comment: Ha, ha, ha. Why the down-vote? This _is_ a correct answer! Anyway, I've gone to some length to explain what chmod means over at SO. for anyone interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995894/umask-setting-changes-after-cd/12811021#12811021

Comment: It is a good answer, and more often than not, is the correct answer for most problems like this. However, it just happened to not be the exact answer for this particular situation.  Or at least missed one problem if there is more than one (the information shown by asker is not complete).  (хороший аватар)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I’m still being asked for a password. If the permissions are right, any other ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Yes. 1 - Pam is not properly configured (weird because it was before). 2 - PubkeyAuthentication, AuthorizedKeysFile, UsePAM not properly set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. 3 - your public key is not in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of the target user. 4 - your ~/.ssh/id_[rd]sa is not the one that is added to autorized_keys on the target. 5 - .ssh/known_hosts has a mismatching fingerprint for server (wild guess, should only be a warning).

Comment: It’s not 3 or 4 because I have verified both of those. Even tried generating a new key and replacing authorized_keys with that, to no avail still. Also tried deleting known_hosts on my local machine to let it re-generate itself. It must be 1 or 2, but I’ve no idea what Pam is!

Comment: The distro should handle PAM, generally you need not worry about it. You can google "yourdistro PAM configuration [wiki|handbook]" to try and verify if everything is correct. Also, try monitoring output of sshd in var/log/daemons or similar. Good luck!

Comment: Running `ssh -vvv -l root domain.com` gives me the following output: http://hastebin.com/veqogiqayo.hs. It seems to think that my public key is `id_rsa`, not `id_rsa.pub`. Is this the problem?

Comment: Also, the contents of my `/var/log/secure` upon failed SSH login: http://hastebin.com/gijaqisesi.md